# How to get gap in date ranges from a period of time

Tags: c#, linq, date, range

I have an initial and a final date range = 1/1/2015 - 1/30/2015

I have these date ranges that represent dates of unavailability.

```
1/5/2015 - 1/10/2015
1/15/2015 - 1/20/2015
1/22/2015 - 1/28/2015
```

I want this output, mainly the dates of availability from the main range:

```
A: 1/1/2015 - 1/4/2015
B: 1/11/2015 - 1/14/2015
C: 1/21/2015 - 1/21/2015
D: 1/29/2015 - 1/30/2015
```

I tried to generate a sequential date range like this in order to get the exception dates with Except()  but I think I'm complicating the thing.

```
 //dtStartDate = 1/1/2015
 //dtEndDate = 1/30/2015  
 var days = (int)(dtEndDate - dtStartDate).TotalDays + 1;
 var completeSeq = Enumerable.Range(0, days).Select(x => dtStartDate.AddDays(x)).ToArray();
```

How can I get the gap of date ranges from period of time.

I other words how can I get the A, B, C and D from this picture

http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=ebe851c

If these dates overlap, they must not be considered only where is a gap.

**----------UPDATE-----------**

I think if I do this:

```
 var range = Enumerable.Range(0, (int)(1/10/2015 - 1/5/2015).TotalDays + 1).Select(i => 1/5/2015.AddDays(i));
 var missing = completeSeq.Except(range).ToArray();
```

for each date range I will have the exclusion of each date range given but still cannot get the gap!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
public static class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        Tuple<DateTime,DateTime> range=Tuple.Create(new DateTime(2015,1,1),new DateTime(2015,1,30));
        Tuple<DateTime,DateTime>[] exclude=new[] {
            Tuple.Create(new DateTime(2015,1,5),new DateTime(2015,1,10)),
            Tuple.Create(new DateTime(2015,1,15),new DateTime(2015,1,20)),
            Tuple.Create(new DateTime(2015,1,22),new DateTime(2015,1,28))
        };
        foreach(Tuple<DateTime,DateTime> r in ExcludeIntervals(range,exclude)) {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}",r.Item1,r.Item2);
        }
    }
    public static IEnumerable<Tuple<DateTime,DateTime>> ExcludeIntervals(Tuple<DateTime,DateTime> range,IEnumerable<Tuple<DateTime,DateTime>> exclude) {
        IEnumerable<Tuple<DateTime,bool>> dates=
            new[] { Tuple.Create(range.Item1.AddDays(-1),true),Tuple.Create(range.Item2.AddDays(1),false) }.
            Concat(exclude.SelectMany(r => new[] { Tuple.Create(r.Item1,false),Tuple.Create(r.Item2,true) })).
            OrderBy(d => d.Item1).ThenBy(d => d.Item2); //Get ordered list of time points where availability can change.
        DateTime firstFreeDate=default(DateTime);
        int count=1; //Count of unavailability intervals what is currently active. Start from 1 to threat as unavailable before range starts.
        foreach(Tuple<DateTime,bool> date in dates) {
            if(date.Item2) { //false - start of unavailability interval. true - end of unavailability interval.
                if(--count==0) { //Become available.
                    firstFreeDate=date.Item1.AddDays(1);
                }
            } else {
                if(++count==1) { //Become unavailable.
                    DateTime lastFreeDate=date.Item1.AddDays(-1);
                    if(lastFreeDate>=firstFreeDate) { //If next unavailability starts right after previous ended, then no gap.
                        yield return Tuple.Create(firstFreeDate,lastFreeDate);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[ideone.com](http://ideone.com/rYnQHR)

Answer (score 2):

I saw your question in my morning today and really liked it, but was busy the whole day. So, got a chance to play with your question and believe me I enjoyed it. Here is my code:-

```
DateTime startDate = new DateTime(2015, 1, 1);
DateTime endDate = new DateTime(2015, 1, 30);
int totalDays = (int)(endDate - startDate).TotalDays + 1;
availability.Add(new Availability { StartDate = endDate, EndDate = endDate });

var result = from x in Enumerable.Range(0, totalDays)
            let d = startDate.AddDays(x)
            from a in availability.Select((v, i) => new { Value = v, Index = i })
            where (a.Index == availability.Count - 1 ? 
                     d <= a.Value.StartDate : d < a.Value.StartDate)
            && (a.Index != 0 ? d > availability[a.Index - 1].EndDate : true)
            group new { d, a } by a.Value.StartDate into g
            select new
            {
                 AvailableDates = String.Format("{0} - {1}",g.Min(x => x.d),
                                                            g.Max(x => x.d))
            };
```

This, definitely need explanation so here it is:-

**Step 1:** Create a range of dates from Jan 01 till Jan 30 using `Enumerable.Range`
**Step 2:** Since after the second unavailable date range, we need to limit the dates selected from last endate till current object startdate, I have calculated `index` so that we can get access to the last enddate.
**Step 3:** Once we get the index, all we need to do is filter the dates except for first date range since we didn't have last object in this case.
**Step 4:** For the last item since we don't have the max range I am adding the endDate to our unavailable list (hope this makes sense).

Here is the [Working Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/B8GA60), if you get confused just remove `group by` and other filters and debug and see the resulting output it will look fairly easy :)

Answer (score 1):

Got a little oopy...

```
public class DateRange
    {
        public DateTime Start { get; set; }
        public DateTime End { get; set; }

        public bool HasStart
        {
            get { return Start != DateTime.MinValue; }
        }
        public bool IsInRange(DateTime date)
        {
            return (date >= this.Start && date <= this.End);
        }

        public List<DateRange> GetAvailableDates(DateRange excludedRange)
        {
            return GetAvailableDates(new List<DateRange>(){excludedRange});
        }

        public List<DateRange> GetAvailableDates(List<DateRange> excludedRanges)
        {
            if (excludedRanges == null)
            {
                return new List<DateRange>() { this };
            }
            var list = new List<DateRange>();
            var aRange = new DateRange();
            var date = this.Start;
            while (date <= this.End)
            {
                bool isInARange = excludedRanges.Any(er => er.HasStart && er.IsInRange(date));
                if (!isInARange)
                {
                    if (!aRange.HasStart)
                    {
                        aRange.Start = date;
                    }
                    aRange.End = date;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (aRange.HasStart)
                    {
                        list.Add(aRange);
                        aRange = new DateRange();
                    }
                }
                date = date.AddDays(1);
            }
            if (aRange.HasStart)
            {
                list.Add(aRange);
            }
            return list;
            }
}
```

Comment: I didn't test if the code returns correct results (yet) but the code looks easier to follow than the other answers